# Flutter CamerPlugin "camera preview" freezed when app goes to background

Tags: flutter, dart, camera

Hi iam using flutter cameraPreview to capture photo, the camera preview works fine but when the camera screen goes to background, while on resumed on that screen the camera screen is frezzed, cant able to view cameraPrview onResume.

mycode:

```
Future<void> _initializeCamera() async {
final cameras = await availableCameras();
final firstCamera = cameras.first;
_controller = CameraController(firstCamera, ResolutionPreset.high);
_initializeControllerFuture = _controller.initialize();
if (!mounted) {
  return;
}
setState(() {
  isCameraReady = true;
});
}


@override
  Widget build(BuildContext context) {
    return Scaffold(
      key: _scaffoldKey,
      body: Stack(children: <Widget>[
        FutureBuilder<void>(
          future: _initializeControllerFuture,
          builder: (context, snapshot) {
            if (snapshot.connectionState == ConnectionState.done) {
              // If the Future is complete, display the preview.
              return CameraPreview(_controller);
            } else {
              return Center(
                  child:
                      CircularProgressIndicator()); // Otherwise, display a loading indicator.
            }
          },
        ),],),);
```

controller is disposed prpoperly.

I want to know why camera preview is disposed while pause.

Answer (score 7, accepted):

Issue is solved by initialised cameraPreview onResume

```
 @override
  void didChangeAppLifecycleState(AppLifecycleState state) {
    if (state == AppLifecycleState.resumed) {
      _controller != null
          ? _initializeControllerFuture = _controller.initialize()
          : null; //on pause camera disposed so we need call again "issue is only for android"
    }
  }
```

On resuming to the page, _controller.initialize will call, so that cameraPreview will works fine.

This is due to cameraPreview runs for long on onPause, it will be disposed..onAndroid i think so..

Comment: To where did you add this method?

Comment: you should override didChangeAppLifecycleState inside your class,  example class CamerPage extends State<InvitationsPage>{}

Comment: Is there another solution. I takes around `0.8` seconds for the camera to restart - so it does not look very nice?

Comment: @NavinKumar could you attach the full example ? using the flutter docs and additionally adding _controller.initialize() in the resumed lifecycle causes an error with some android devices that the controller was initialized twice

Comment: https://navinkumar0118.medium.com/take-a-picture-using-flutter-camera-a9c11d282632. refer this blog

Answer (score 1):

```
import 'package:camera/camera.dart';
import 'package:flutter/material.dart';
// import 'package:flutter/services.dart';

late List<CameraDescription> _cameras;

Future<void> main() async {
  WidgetsFlutterBinding.ensureInitialized();

  _cameras = await availableCameras();
  runApp(const CameraApp());
}

/// CameraApp is the Main Application.
class CameraApp extends StatefulWidget {
  /// Default Constructor
  const CameraApp({Key? key}) : super(key: key);

  @override
  State<CameraApp> createState() => _CameraAppState();
}

class _CameraAppState extends State<CameraApp> with WidgetsBindingObserver {
  late CameraController controller;
  // late AppLifecycleState _appLifecycleState;

  @override
  void initState() {
    super.initState();
    // _appLifecycleState = AppLifecycleState.resumed;
    WidgetsBinding.instance.addObserver(this);
    controller = CameraController(_cameras[0], ResolutionPreset.max);
    cameraInit();
  }

  void cameraInit() {
    controller.initialize().then((_) {
      if (!mounted) {
        return;
      }
      setState(() {});
    }).catchError((Object e) {
      if (e is CameraException) {
        switch (e.code) {
          case 'CameraAccessDenied':
            // Handle access errors here.
            break;
          default:
            // Handle other errors here.
            break;
        }
      }
    });
  }

  @override
  void dispose() {
    controller.dispose();
    WidgetsBinding.instance.removeObserver(this);
    super.dispose();
  }

  @override
  void didChangeAppLifecycleState(AppLifecycleState state) {
    setState(() {
      // _appLifecycleState = state;
    });
    if (state == AppLifecycleState.resumed) {
      // App is in the foreground
      print('App is in the foreground');

      cameraInit();
    } else if (state == AppLifecycleState.paused) {
      // App is in the background
      print('App is in the background');
    }
  }

  @override
  Widget build(BuildContext context) {
    if (!controller.value.isInitialized) {
      return Container();
    }
    return MaterialApp(
      home: CameraPreview(controller),
    );
  }
}
```

Comment: Try to add some explanation please, not only the code. What is the clue of your code? It would help those who look for plenty of Q/A and don't have time to delve into each and every code snippet.